# How can I create the lookup table using PDA

Tags: versionedtransactions

I want to create the lookup table using PDA address which is  the offCurve. So, I am getting the error of signature verification fail while making the create lookupTable by PDA

I am using this code

```
const [lookupTableInst, lookupTableAddress] =
      AddressLookupTableProgram.createLookupTable({
        authority: PDA,
        payer: data.sender,
        recentSlot: await connection.getSlot(),
      });

const lookupMessage = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: data.sender,
      recentBlockhash: lbh.blockhash,
      instructions: [lookupTableInst],
    }).compileToV0Message();

const lookupTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(lookupMessage);

const signed = await wallet.signTransaction(lookupTransaction);

const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(signed, {
    skipPreflight: true,
    preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
  });

const r = await connection.confirmTransaction(txid, "confirmed");
```

So this getting the "signtaure verfication fail" error
Any clue about this ?

Comment: How are you getting `wallet` and `data.sender`, are they the same or different?

Comment: Wallet is getting from the wallet provider react from @solana/wallet-adapter-react and data.sender is the publickey of the wallet. They are same

Answer (score 2):

First, the authority has to sign the call to the address lookup table program
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/ac65343f01508add0651fae7153cac6c4090ade0/programs/address-lookup-table/src/instruction.rs#L18 as you can see documented here

Second, a PDA is a program-derived address, as a result only the program it is derived from can sign it.

You have to call that program to be able to perform a signed cross program invocation to create lookup table.

Comment: Yeah, but I require the transaction instruction as to call the program for pda, How can I get the transaction instruction. First need to create the message like "lookupMessage" ?